How can I make a custom post status private or draft?
I have the following code where the "private" value is set to true but posts with this status show up on the front end. In the admin add/edit screen the post shows "Visibility" as "Public".
function needs_video_status(){
    register_post_status( 'needs-video', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Draft - Needs Video', 'post' ),
        'public'                    => false,
        'private'                   => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => true,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Draft - Needs Video <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Draft - Needs Video <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'needs_video_status' );

Is it even possible to have a custom post status set to private visibility? Alternatively, is there a way to set a custom post status as a draft?

this is all assuming you're using a standard main post loop with no query_posts/WP_Query/get_posts? And you aren't using a page builder/shortcode/widget to fetch and display the post?

Yes that's correct. I have a child Understrap theme so it's directly hitting the single.php file. I'm guessing the only way to prevent it from displaying on the front end is a redirect to 404.php if the post has the needs-video status?

it's hitting none of those files, WP loads the template file after it's parsed the URL loaded the plugins and ran the query. When it loads a theme template file it knows everything already it's just for displaying the results. So a redirect to 404.php makes no sense and isn't a thing
